# number of checked rows in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list with items and checkboxes and want to return the number of checked rows. My directive looks like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="person in list">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected" >
        <label ng-class="{blue:list.length>3,red:list.length<=3}"> {{person.name}}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What would be the angular way to display the nr of checked persons?

http://plnkr.co/edit/jJrH44?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/5HzZA23D0P78nEzvmUpf?p=preview

```
 number of checked lines:<span>{{ (list| filter:{selected:true}).length }}</span>
```

but you should change your list template as

```
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="person.selected" >
```

to link checkbox and model value